# logarithmic scale on x_axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have made a chart on my form.I want to set the scale of x_axis as logrithim.I mean that I have several point added to my chart.When showing the chart,I want the x_axis be shown in logarithim scale.How can I do that? .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by enabling Logarithms on the X-Axis:

Assuming you have only one chart area:

```
this.chart_YourChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
```